# How can i create a vector compass arrow

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector

I'm very new at designing in Adobe Photoshop CC 2017.Although i am a developer,from time ti time i need this program in order to create some images.
Now i want to create an arrow and its white circle separately that was drawn on the screen of phone.How can i achieve this.Any suggestion would be welcome or links to do this.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems are you having?  You can create vectors in Photoshop, but it's not the ideal tool. Adobe's vector image editor is Illustrator.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer @Billy i'm green in this part of designing,i will also download that program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To create the arrow**

Open a document in Photoshop.

Step 1: Create a rectangle using the Rectangle Tool.

Step 2: Select Path Selection Tool. Then click on top left anchor point. Right click and then select delete anchor point.

Step 3: Duplicate the layer. Right Click and select flip horizontal.

Step 4: Select both the layers and duplicate it. Click right and select flip vertical.

Step 5. Group the 4 layers and create a duplicate. Right click and select Rotate 90 degree clockwise.

Step 6: Ctr T and reduce the size. Duplicate the groups and rotate it by using Ctr T.

Step 7: Create a new layer and draw a circle on the top of the arrow. Fill color will be similar to the arrow color. click on stroke to select background color.

Step 8: Duplicate the the circle. Ctr T and reduce the size.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much,I tried but couldn't do,could you send me this file. tehedli@gmail.com .